# How do I use the output of "pgrep" with "ps -p"?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, conky

I'm trying to display Conkys process uptime. If I type the following into the terminal one line at a time it all works and I get the result I'm after.

```
getPID=$(pgrep -f conky)

conkyPID=$(ps -p $getPID -o etime=)

echo $conkyPID
```

Naive me thought a bash script would look like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
getPID=$(pgrep -f conky)
conkyPID=$(ps -p "$getPID" -o etime=)
echo "$conkyPID"
```

I've asked a couple of friends and the most helpful info I received was I need a command line separator and I think it's a `|`.
I've tried a lot of variations of brackets, quotes and pipes to no avail.
In my experimenting it appears the 2nd line has no idea I have set the variable "getPID" in the previous line.
When I run the script I get.

```
error: process ID list syntax error
```

Output of running script with `bash -x`:

```
ricky@Shitmobile:~$ bash -x conkypid.sh
++ pgrep -f conky 
+ getPID='45990
153098'
++ ps -p '45990 153098' -o etime=
error: process ID list syntax error
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, since each line is a separate command, it doesn't make any difference - the script should work: (note that `$getPID` and `$conkyPID` should be quoted)

```
#!/bin/bash
getPID=$(pgrep -f conky)
conkyPID=$(ps -p "$getPID" -o etime=)
echo "$conkyPID"
```

I have tested, and this works fine for me.

However, since `pgrep` can return multiple values as output (which is true in your case), you should isolate the output so you only fetch the earliest PID. So modify like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
getPID=$(pgrep -fo conky)
# getPID=$(pgrep -f conky | head -n 1) # another, but not as elegant method
conkyPID=$(ps -p "$getPID" -o etime=)
echo "$conkyPID"
```

This will only fetch the first PID for conky, and display the elapsed time for this PID.

On the other hand, if you wish to process all PIDs that might be output by `pgrep`, then you can pipe the output to `xargs` with `ps` like so:

```bash
 pgrep -f conky | xargs -I _ ps -p _ -o etime=
```

Where `-I _` will both process only one arguments line(*`pgrep` outputs each single PID on a newline by default*) at a time and pass it to `ps -p _ ...` in-place/position of the place-holder `_`. ... You can also assign the value/s to the variable directly with command substitution and even shorten your script like so:

```bash
conkyPID=$(pgrep -f conky | xargs -I _ ps -p _ -o etime=)
echo "$conkyPID"
```

Comment: I added a fix by taking only the first PID with `head -n 1`.

Comment: Bazinga, head did the trick. Thank you. I cant even remember why I wanted conky uptime, but found I learnt a ton in the process.

Comment: Thanks @Raffa for being the first to point out the probability of more than one process with conky in the name. I didn't/don't see any other conky processes in the system monitor, if I had I don't think I would have been quite so naive looking for a PID by a keyword that was in more than one process.

Comment: @justchillin You're welcome ... `-f` doesn't really match the process's name but, rather matches the full command line(*or part of it*) that was used to launch a process while system monitor shows exact process's name ... So, it's probable that the other process just happened to have `conky` in its command or filename or as an argument.

Comment: fyi `pgrep` has a `-o` / `--oldest` and `-n` / `--newest` that would provide an alternate method for selecting just a single PID

Comment: @steeldriver right, I remember that now..

Comment: @Raffa please add the `xargs` solution - I'm not that familiar with it. 

Comment: @ArturMeinild done :-)